# C++ Weird characters printed to the screen

Tags: c++

Thank you sp2danny for the answer!

HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEERECORD_H
#define EMPLOYEERECORD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class EmployeeRecord
{
    char m_sLastName[31];  // employee last name
    char m_sFirstName[31]; // employee first name

    EmployeeRecord();     // default constructor
    EmployeeRecord(int ID, char *fName, char *lName, int dept, double sal);
};

#endif
```

SOURCE FILE:

```
#include "EmployeeRecord.h"

//constructor 1 (default)
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord()
{
    m_iEmployeeID = 0;
    m_sLastName == "";
    m_sFirstName == "";
    m_iDeptID = 0;
    m_dSalary = 0.0;
}

// this constructor shall set the member variables to the values passed into the function
EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(int ID, char *fName, char *lName, int dept, double sal)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    m_iEmployeeID = ID;
    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        m_sFirstName[i] = *(fName + i);
        m_sLastName[i] = *(lName + i);
    }
    m_iDeptID = dept;
    m_dSalary = sal;
}

// destructor - cleans up and deallocates any memory that pointers within this class may have referenced to
EmployeeRecord::~EmployeeRecord(){};


// this function shall print to the screen all data found in the employee's record
void EmployeeRecord::printRecord()
{
    cout << "Employee ID:     " << m_iEmployeeID << endl;
    cout << "First Name:      " << m_sFirstName << endl;
    cout << "Last Name:       " << m_sLastName << endl;
    cout << "Department ID:   " << m_iDeptID << endl;
    cout << "Salary:        $ " << m_dSalary << endl;
}
```

HOW I CALL IT:

```
/*******************************************************************
*   main function for project Prog1
*******************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "EmployeeRecord.h"

int main(void)
{

    int answer, employee_id, dept_id;
    unsigned int i;
    char  firstname[31], lastname[31];
    double *salary, _salary;

    salary = &_salary;


    EmployeeRecord Employee1 = EmployeeRecord();
    firstname[0] = 'J';
    firstname[1] = 'h';
    firstname[2] = 'o';
    firstname[3] = 'n';
    firstname[4] = 'n';
    firstname[5] = 'y';
    lastname[0] = 'D';
    lastname[1] = 'o';
    lastname[2] = 'e';
    lastname[3] = 'b';
    lastname[4] = 'e';
    lastname[5] = 'r';
    EmployeeRecord Employee2 = EmployeeRecord(0, firstname, lastname, 0, 0.0);
    Employee2.printRecord();
    system("pause");
```

So say I have set m_sFirstName equal to "Johnny" and m_sLastName equal to "Doeber" where m_sFirstName[0] = 'J', m_sLastName = 'D', etc...
Everytime the printRecord function is called, I get this result:

```
Fist Name: Johnny########################### (2 more spaces than were allocated)
Last Name: Doeber#########################Johnny###########################
```

where # is the null character (looks very weird in the real program)

So not only is the m_sFirstName not printing the first 3 characters to the screen correctly, but the whole messed up version of m_sFirstName is being added to the end of the m_sLastName character array...

How in the world have I done this to myself?

Comment: What do you think this does? `m_sLastName == "";`.

Comment: It puts a null character for every character of the character string m_sLastName. Also, I have had it defined multiple ways, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: No, it definitely doesn't do that. It has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @tomkelley13: First, not *every* char gets 0, only *one*, with such an assignment. Second, this isn´t an assignment, but a comparison.

Comment: Ok, so I haven't assigned null values to my character array? So how would I correct this?

Comment: @tomkelley13 ...correction, this isn´t even a std::string. Another error. If you want all 0 values, use a loop and = instead of ==.

Comment: @deviantfan What assignment? And since when are arrays assignable anyway? ;-)

Comment: At the absolute minimum, you allocate space for 32 character for the employee name, and then you write __35__ characters to those arrays.

Comment: @Bill Lynch You sir, just fixed half of my problem... It still adds the firstname to the end of the lastname though...

Comment: @tomkelley13: Here's my honest feeling about this question. __1.__ There's a __ton__ of code that is unrelated to what you claim your issue is. You claim that you're having problems with the name member of your struct. So why leave in the question code about the department. __2.__ We don't know exactly how you're calling these functions. For example, if you pass this function a string literal `"John"`, then you'll still have errors because that same loop is accessing beyond the end of the string literal. __3.__ In other words: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Bill Lynch I trimmed it up a bit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the clearing of name-fields in the constructor should read

```
m_sLastName[0] = 0
m_sFirstName[0] = 0;
```

the setting of name-fields in the other constructor should read

```
strncpy( m_sFirstName, fName, 31 );
strncpy( m_sLastName,  lName, 31 );
```

the locals in main should be set with

```
strncpy(firstname, "Johnny", 31 );
strncpy(lasname,   "Doeber", 31 );
```

not that those locals are needed

you need `<string.h>` for `strncpy`

Also note, your professor should get an F for this assignment, starting with C is the *worst* way to teach C++

Comment: Wow, perfect answer. Nicely done.

Comment: Not perfect at all, prefer sizeof to magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

#### Comparison vs Assignment

This line of code:

```
m_sLastName == "";
```

Does nothing. It compares the pointer to an empty string to an array of characters. And computes if they point to the same piece of memory (not the same contents). And then we throw away that result.

If you want to initialize `m_sLastName` with all null characters, then you should do:

```
memset(m_sLastName, '\0', sizeof(m_sLastName));
```

By not doing this, `m_sLastName` is initialized to unspecified values. That is, random junk.

If instead, you'd like those strings to be empty strings, then you can simply do:

```
m_sLastName[0] = '\0';
```

#### How do we copy strings?

Your current code to copy the value of the name to the object **almost** works. You don't null terminate the string, and you assume that the string passed in is 31 characters long. In your `main()`, this is true. But it's a really bad thing to assume.

Let's fix that:

```
strncpy(m_sLastName, lName, 31);
m_sLastName[30] = '\0'; // If lName was too long, then strncpy won't null terminate the string.
```

We could also use `snprintf()`, which is a bit slower, but safer.

```
snprintf(m_sLastName, sizeof(m_sLastName), "%s", lName);
```

#### The string that you created in main()

`firstname` and `lastname` in main aren't null terminated. They really should be. So you need to add:

```
firstname[6] = '\0';
lastname[6] = '\0';
```

#### What would code look like that implemented all of this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class EmployeeRecord {
    private:
        char m_sLastName[31];
        char m_sFirstName[31];

    public:
        EmployeeRecord();
        EmployeeRecord(int ID, const char *fName, const char *lName, int dept, double sal);

    public:
        void printRecord();
};

EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord() {
    memset(m_sFirstName, '\0', sizeof(m_sFirstName));
    memset(m_sLastName, '\0', sizeof(m_sLastName));
}

EmployeeRecord::EmployeeRecord(int ID, const char *fName, const char *lName, int dept, double sal) {
    snprintf(m_sFirstName, sizeof(m_sLastName), "%s", fName);
    snprintf(m_sLastName, sizeof(m_sLastName), "%s", lName);
}

void EmployeeRecord::printRecord() {
    cout << "First Name:      " << m_sFirstName << endl;
    cout << "Last Name:       " << m_sLastName << endl;
}

int main() {
    EmployeeRecord Employee1 = EmployeeRecord();
    Employee1.printRecord();
    printf("\n");

    char firstname[31] = "Jhonny";
    char lastname[31] = "Doeber";
    EmployeeRecord Employee2 = EmployeeRecord(0, firstname, lastname, 0, 0.0);
    Employee2.printRecord();
    printf("\n");

    EmployeeRecord Employee3 = EmployeeRecord(0, "John", "Smith", 0, 0.0);
    Employee3.printRecord();
    printf("\n");
}
```

#### What would running that code look like?

```
First Name:      
Last Name:       

First Name:      Jhonny
Last Name:       Doeber

First Name:      John
Last Name:       Smith
```

#### What is actually in `Employee3.firstname`?

So, here's what I know about Employee3's firstname. There's 31 characters available for space. I know that the first 5 contain `{'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\0'}`.

I don't know what the remainder contains. It likely has some junk that isn't all null characters. The thing is, we don't care. The valid content of the string ends at the first null characters.

Comment: It would be easier to value initialize `m_sLastName` rather than do the whole memset thing.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree, but then we have to get into why we have to do that in the initializer list instead of the body of the constructor. And I think that might be a bit much to get into at this point.

Comment: True. It might also confuse OP's "professor".

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string` for `m_sFirstName` and `m_sLastName`, and the behaviour will be much closer to what you are expecting.

Comment: Those two variables have to be character arrays. They can't be strings.

Comment: Why? What different are you expecting?

Comment: It's a project assignment. Professor just wants it like that, I'm assuming just to make it harder.

Comment: Ok, so a school project. Read up the different between pointers and arrays, and check out `strcpy()` and family of functions for copying the characters.